# Как интегрировать phpdesigner 8 и GIT?

Tags: git

Вопрос, собственно, в теме. Скачал себе phpdesigner 8 и не могу его подключить к ГИТу. Что и как делать? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

[Git Integration with phpDesigner 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480822/git-integration-with-phpdesigner-8)

**Обновление**

Попробуйте закрыть проект, удалить директорию, созданную `phpDesigner`, и открыть снова. `phpStorm`'у помогает.

Comment: я это видел. ввожу путь и нажимаю ок, и .... ничего не происходит. вкладка ГИТ остается не активной. Как это сделать?